# Multiple functions from one controller

Tags: php, laravel, charts, routes, controller

How do you access multiple functions from one controller in a laravel project routing file?
Syntax will suffice thanks.

These are the two routes I want to combine

```
Route::get('openreports/chart', 'InventoryController@gradeCodeDeliveriesChart')->middleware('auth')>name('openreports/chart'); 

Route::get('openreports/chart', 'InventoryController@yearDeliveriesChart')->middleware('auth')->name('openreports/chart');
```

Comment: Can you please be more elaborate, what do you mean by 'combine two routes' ? If you want two different routes to go into the same controller method, then just change `'InventoryController@yearDeliveriesChart'` to `'InventoryController@gradeCodeDeliveriesChart` for example

Comment: Yeah exactly that I want to combine two routes into one but these routes I listed above go into two different functions so is there a way to combine the two statements into one or maybe a way to mention them separately

Comment: Not really, AFAIK. Just a heads up, your route naming is incorrect as per route naming convention. It should be something like `->name('openreports.chart')`.

Comment: "_I want to combine two routes into one_" How is your app supposed to know which method to trigger when you hit `/openreports/chart`? Have _one_ route with _one_ method and decide in that method what to show/run

Comment: Found the solution .. in the relevant blade file, I combined the two script sections for the two routes. Apparently keeping them separated was the problem. And renaming them as separate routes using the naming convention tip by @Skywarth helped as well